# is there a way for me to fix the " Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context" in this kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, error-handling

1. This keeps displaying an error

```kotlin
        fun main() {
            println("Hello, world!")
        }
        fun coinFlip(timesToFlip: Int){
            var heads = 0
            var tails = 0
            fun flip(): Int{
                for(i in 1..timesToFlip){
                    var randomNumbers = (1..2).random()
                    if (randomNumbers = 1){
                         heads += 1
                    } else {
                         tails += 1
                    }
                }
                return tails
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume in `randomNumbers = 1` you intended to check if `randomNumbers` value is `1`. In Kotlin, we check for equality using `==` operator. `=` is an assignment operator. So you need to replace this line with:

```kotlin
if (randomNumbers == 1) {
```

You can find the full list of Kotlin operators here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/keyword-reference.html#operators-and-special-symbols